# Why does the location where the user runs gradlew from affect the output?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

If I have a directory structure such as:

```
/someDir/
    /AndroidStudioProjectDir/
```

And run gradlew from the command line like this:

```
/someDir/AndroidStudioProjectDir$ ./gradlew tasks
```

(i.e. I am in the someDir/AndroidStudioProjectDir dir when I run the command)

Then it will list dozens of tasks, including my own. But however if I run it like this:

```
/someDir$ ./AndroidStudioProjectDir/gradlew tasks
```

(i.e. now I am in the someDir directory when I run the command line)

Then it only lists a few tasks (the Build Setup tasks and the Help tasks).

Why is there a difference depending upon the currently location where the command is issued from?

Why isn't running gradlew from within projectDir the same as running projectDir/gradlew from one directory back?

Comment: do you have gradlew script in both directories?

Comment: No. There's one in /someDir/AndroidStudioProjectDir/ and one in /someDIr/AndroidStudioProjectDir/app/.  All the gradle files/locations were created by Android Studio, I haven't changed anything. Just trying to understand this behavior, I thought it should be the same gradlew running in both instances and thus should have same behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens because the gradle command looks for a file called `build.gradle` in the **current directory**.

You can find more [info here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_using_tasks.html#N10A97).

Running the command:

```
/someDir/AndroidStudioProjectDir$ ./gradlew tasks
```

the current directory is `/someDir/AndroidStudioProjectDir$` where there is the `build.gradle` script defined by the android project.

Running the command:

```
/someDir$ ./AndroidStudioProjectDir/gradlew tasks
```

the current dir is `/someDir$`. In this case gradle will not found the build.gradle file and will list only the default tasks.

---

You can use the `--project-dir` [command line option](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/command_line_interface.html) to tell gradle where to look for `build.gradle`:

```
/someDir$ ./AndroidStudioProjectDir/gradlew tasks --project-dir ./AndroidStudioProjectDir/
```